# How do you simplify product operators divided by one another?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

[image]

I am working on finding the uniformly most powerful rejection region. However, I am having difficultly simplifying the bottom expression. The PDF is given in the first image. I'm terrible at algebra, but so far I have $(\frac{2.5}{\beta})^n$ as the first part. I'm not sure how to simplify the rest. Any help? Sorry if this a noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\displaystyle\frac{2.5}{(1+x)^{2.5+1}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\beta}{(1+x)^{\beta+1}}}
  &=& \frac{2.5}{\beta}(1+x)^{\beta-2.5}
\end{eqnarray}$$

you have

$$\left(\frac{2.5}{\beta}\right)^n\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)^{\beta-2.5}$$

I don't think that simplifies nicely beyond that.